# Fresh Rails 4 app is not recognizing `rails` commands, insists that I use `rails new`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4

I've successfully made a new application with the `rails new` command from a clone of the Rails master branch. The app looks fine, and is definitely Rails 4. But when I try to run any other `rails` command, the prompt gives me:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
  ... etc etc
```

I've tried `rails`, `bundle exec rails`, and `bin/rails`, all give the same prompt. My steps for creating a new Rails 4 app were:

1. Clone the Rails master branch to my local machine
2. Create a new rvm gemset, and use it (1.9.3)
3. Run `rails/railties/bin/rails new myapp --edge -T --skip-index-html`
4. `cd myapp` and run `bundle install` and `bundle update` just to be sure
5. Run any `rails` command

What am I doing wrong? `rvm-prompt` suggests I am using the right gemset. One thing I did notice is that even when I remove jbuilder from my Gemfile and run a `bundle update`, it still appears in my `gem list`. Is something wrong with my rvm here?

`rails-v` output is 'Rails 4.0.0.beta'

Comment: what else would you expect from rails command to do?

Comment: `rails g`, `rails s`, `rails c` ..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, report back to ruby on rails issues tracking: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Comment: I still have that same problem in the beta. Did you finally report it on github issues? If you did, can you share a link?

Answer (score 1):

See my first comment here, it contains a possible fix : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9715

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my 'bin' folder was missing.