# Trying to start rails console in rails app root gives me the

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in the root of my `Rails` app and have attempted to start the rails console a various number of ways, including `rails c`, `bundle exec rails c`, `spring rails c`, and `bin/rails c` to no avail. It simply returns the a message as if I had just typed in `rails` without any arguments.

Here's the message I get:

```
>  rails c
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

I've used `RVM` to uninstall and reinstall my `ruby` version and have uninstalled and reinstalled my gemset.

I suspect it has something to do with `spring` but can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

So after stumbling across these two stack overflow posts, [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942863/fresh-rails-4-app-is-not-recognizing-rails-commands-insists-that-i-use-rails), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942863/fresh-rails-4-app-is-not-recognizing-rails-commands-insists-that-i-use-rails), which directed me to this Github [**issue**](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9715#issuecomment-38225491) in the `rails` repo.

Basically, running `rake rails:update:bin` generated new `bins` that ended up solving my problem.